# Can't catch exception in PHP Selenium webdriver

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, exception

I'm trying to catch errors in pages that timeout when running them with Facebook's PHP webdriver.

The page load and wait are both succesfully called, but the TimeOutException thrown by wait() doesn't get caught in either catch block.

```
try {
    $this->webDriver->get(self::BASE_URI.$uri_to_check);
    $this->webDriver->wait($webDriver, 100, 500)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('My Page'));
}
catch (TimeOutException $e) {
    return "Timeout Exception because".$e->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    return "Failed to load page because".$e->getMessage();
}
```

How can I catch this?

Comment: Are there any errors happening at all? I'm not sure but I think it has something to do with page load and which element you want to ensure is visible.  Perhaps something along these lines? http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#waitForElementVisible

Comment: Same issue here... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to use "Implicit wait" as opposed to "Explicit wait". Your example is making use of "Explicit wait" i.e. will try for a number of sendcond then sleep (not timeout). Refer to the [php-driver wiki](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait).

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong parameters to the `wait()` method. The params are `$timeout_in_second` and `$interval_in_millisecond`. So if you for example want to wait up to 15 seconds and check the title every 500 ms (0,5 sec), you must call it this way:

```
$this->wd->wait(15, 500)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('My Page')
);
```

And also note the default parameters (30 seconds, 250 milliseconds), so you don't need to pass them at all:

```
$this->wd->wait()->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('My Page')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I eventually fixed it by supplying the full path to the TimeoutException:

```
try {
    $this->webDriver->get(self::BASE_URI.$uri_to_check);
    $this->webDriver->wait($webDriver, 100, 500)->until(
    WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('My Page'));
}
catch (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeoutException $e) {
    return "Timeout Exception because".$e->getMessage();
}
```

The exception is then caught.